# Rake db:create mysql/rake version issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am following this [backbone rails turotial](http://robertogds.com/post/3324511589/howto-backbone-js-using-rails-3).

The tutorial says they are using Ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.3.

I am using Ruby 1.9.3, and I created an rvm gemset for this tutorial and installed rails 3.0.3  into the gemset.

I ran bundle install which installed mysql2 version 0.3.11

When I ran `rake db:create` I got this error:

> WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.3.11) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1
>
> WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x

So I ran:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
gem install mysql --version 0.2
rake db:create
```

Then I got this error:

> Could not find mysql2-0.3.11 in any of the sources
>
> Try running `bundle install`.

If I run `bundle install` it takes me back to the first problem.

Not sure what the I should try next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

place in Gemfile

`gem 'mysql2','0.2.7'`

then run

`bundle install`

Comment: Yes, this fixed it, might want to clarify though that the first line goes into the Gemfile.